# BeautifulSoup google trend

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to the programming world and have just finished understanding the very basics of Python. I have just started practicing web crawling and have faced a problem already. I have written a very simple code using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

response = urlopen('https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
for anchor in soup.select(".list-item-title"):
    print(anchor)
```

I want to retrieve the names of the recently trending stories; however, the code above is not functioning as it's supposed to and returns a blank.

I would be grateful if someone could point out the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Trends(url) is dynamic meaning data is generated by JavaScript and BeautifulSoup can't render javaSceipt.So, You need automation tool something like selenium with BeautifulSoup`. Please just run the code.

**Scripts:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
#driver.close()

for anchor in soup.select(".list-item-title"):
    print(anchor.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Meta
Lupus
Liga Europy
Chelsea
Prova do lider
Masks in Kenya
UANL
Jussie Smollett
ישי ריבו
Winter storm warning
```